# CIFilter Gaussian Blur edges size

Tags: ios, objective-c, cifilter

I am using `CIFilter Gaussian Blur` to blur a UIImage. Image gets blurred but the edges get more blurred. I want the image to be blurred equally.Following is the output:

[image]

I don't want the extra white lines to appear on the image. Following is the code that I am using:

```
 - (UIImage *)setupBlurredImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:image];

    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];

    [filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0f] forKey:@"inputRadius"];

    CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];


    CIFilter *affineClampFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineClamp"];


    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[inputImage extent]];



    UIImage *blurimage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];


    //add our blurred image to the scrollview
    return blurimage;
}
```

I tried all teh techniques given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839729/correct-crop-of-cigaussianblur). None worked for me.

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?