# Gaussian blur on full screen

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, gaussian, core-image

I want to blur the whole screen of my iOS app, and I can't use `UIBlurEffect` because I want to be able to control the blurriness. So I'm trying to use `CIGaussianBlur`, but I'm having trouble with the edges of the screen.

I'm taking a screenshot of the screen, and then running it through a `CIFilter` with `CIGaussianBlur`, converting the `CIImage` back to `UIImage`, and adding the new blurred image on top of the screen.

**Here's my code:**

```
    let layer = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.layer
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)

    layer!.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let blurRadius = 5
    var ciimage: CIImage = CIImage(image: screenshot)!
    var filter: CIFilter = CIFilter(name:"CIGaussianBlur")!
    filter.setDefaults()
    filter.setValue(ciimage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter.setValue(blurRadius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

    let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
    let result = filter.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage!
    let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(result, fromRect: view.frame)

    let finalImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)


    let blurImageView = UIImageView(frame: view.frame)
    blurImageView.image = finalImage
    blurImageView.sizeToFit()
    blurImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    blurImageView.center = view.center
    view.addSubview(blurImageView)
```

**Here is what I see:**

[image: Gaussian blur applied to screenshot]

It looks almost right except the edges. It seems that the blurrisness is taking off from the blur radius to the edge. I tried playing with the context size but couldn't seem to make it work.

**How can I make the blur go all the way to the edges?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is happening because the gaussian blur filter samples pixels outside the edges of the image. But because there are no pixels, you get this weird artefact. You can use `"CIAffineClamp"` filter to "extend" your image infinitely in all directions.

Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18138742/762779

I tried running your code with chained 'CIAffineClamp-> CIGaussianBlur' filters and got good results.

```
let layer = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.layer
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)

layer!.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

let blurRadius = 5
let ciimage: CIImage = CIImage(image: screenshot)!

// Added "CIAffineClamp" filter 
let affineClampFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineClamp")!
affineClampFilter.setDefaults()
affineClampFilter.setValue(ciimage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let resultClamp = affineClampFilter.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey)

// resultClamp is used as input for "CIGaussianBlur" filter
let filter: CIFilter = CIFilter(name:"CIGaussianBlur")!
filter.setDefaults()
filter.setValue(resultClamp, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter.setValue(blurRadius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)


let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
let result = filter.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage!
let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(result, fromRect: ciimage.extent) // changed to ciiimage.extend 

let finalImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)

let blurImageView = UIImageView(frame: view.frame)
blurImageView.image = finalImage
blurImageView.sizeToFit()
blurImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
blurImageView.center = view.center
view.addSubview(blurImageView)
```

Comment: You Sir, deserve some kind of achievement for that answer.. It worked like a charm.! Thank you :)