# I don't want to extent in CIGaussianBlur of CIFilter

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, uiimage

When I apply GaussianBlur, the edge is remained like this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839729/correct-crop-of-cigaussianblur)

I know the problem that is image size. Blur effect is become bigger than source image. But I don't know how to apply original image size :(

here is my code:

```
func applyBlurEffect(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let imageToBlur = CIImage(image: image)
    let blurfilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
    blurfilter!.setValue(imageToBlur, forKey: "inputImage")
    let resultImage = blurfilter!.value(forKey: "outputImage") as! CIImage
    let croppedImage: CIImage = resultImage.cropping(to: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageToBlur!.extent.size.width, height: imageToBlur!.extent.size.height))
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let blurredImage = UIImage(cgImage: context.createCGImage(croppedImage, from: croppedImage.extent)!)
    return blurredImage
}
```

I'd like to apply image size which is input in func. Anybod know about that?

Comment: Based on this question (Obj-C based) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839729/correct-crop-of-cigaussianblur your might just need to change how you work with *resultImage*... use it directly in *createCGImage*, and use *imageToBlur.extent* for the rect to use. There are other things to try if this doesn't work, but it does sound like this may work.

Comment: @dfd thank you for comment. I tried to that, but image is become blank.. :(

Answer (score 3):

**1.**
I don't know if this will suit your needs but you can try the `UIBlurEffect` as Apple does in the Notification Center (dark, light or very light):

```
func applyBlurEffectTo(imageView: UIImageView) {
    guard !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled() else {
        return
    }

    imageView.backgroundColor = .clear

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = imageView.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    imageView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
}
```

(*I think it's too light and the `.dark` option for the effect is too dark :) You'll want to remove the tint.*)

**2.** 
Or use this `UIImage extension` (a little overkill but will work 100%, it's partially how the first case implemented under the hood):

```
import UIKit
import Accelerate

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.image = imageView.image?.applyBlurWithRadius(5)
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func applyBlurWithRadius(_ blurRadius: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        if (size.width < 1 || size.height < 1) { return nil }
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else {  return nil }

        let __FLT_EPSILON__ = CGFloat(FLT_EPSILON)
        let screenScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        let imageRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
        var effectImage = self

        let hasBlur = blurRadius > __FLT_EPSILON__

        if hasBlur {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, screenScale)
            guard let effectInContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return  nil }

            effectInContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
            effectInContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: -size.height)
            effectInContext.draw(cgImage, in: imageRect)

            var effectInBuffer = createEffectBuffer(effectInContext)

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, screenScale)

            guard let effectOutContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return  nil }
            var effectOutBuffer = createEffectBuffer(effectOutContext)

            if hasBlur {
                let inputRadius = blurRadius * screenScale
                let d = floor(inputRadius * 3.0 * CGFloat(sqrt(2 * M_PI) / 4 + 0.5))
                var radius = UInt32(d)
                if radius % 2 != 1 {
                    radius += 1
                }

                let imageEdgeExtendFlags = vImage_Flags(kvImageEdgeExtend)
                vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, nil, 0, 0, radius, radius, nil, imageEdgeExtendFlags)
                vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectOutBuffer, &effectInBuffer, nil, 0, 0, radius, radius, nil, imageEdgeExtendFlags)
                vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, nil, 0, 0, radius, radius, nil, imageEdgeExtendFlags)
            }

            effectImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, screenScale)

        guard let outputContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }

        outputContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        outputContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: -size.height)
        outputContext.draw(cgImage, in: imageRect)

        if hasBlur {
            outputContext.saveGState()
            outputContext.draw(effectImage.cgImage!, in: imageRect)
            outputContext.restoreGState()
        }

        let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return outputImage
    }

    private func createEffectBuffer(_ context: CGContext) -> vImage_Buffer {
        let data = context.data
        let width = vImagePixelCount(context.width)
        let height = vImagePixelCount(context.height)
        let rowBytes = context.bytesPerRow
        return vImage_Buffer(data: data, height: height, width: width, rowBytes: rowBytes)
    }
}
```

2-nd option the result:
[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't want to blur effect because I have to draw image. blur effect can't draw the image :(

Comment: Solution 2 is a hard to find if you want a solid example of blur with more control over the radiux