# Using CIAffineClamp and CIGaussianBlur with CALayer backgroundFilters

Tags: objective-c, macos, calayer, core-image, cifilter

I'm using `CALayer.backgroundFilters` to blur sibling layers behind my layer, but I can't seem to get the `CIAffineClamp` filter to work as expected. It should prevent the edges of the blurred image from being softened (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839729/correct-crop-of-cigaussianblur)).

Instead, the `CIAffineClamp` does nothing at all. I've tested both with and without, and the same image is created. **Note:** The blur *is* working as expected, but not the clamp.

---

I have a `CIFilter` subclass with an `outputImage` method like so:

```
- (CIImage *)outputImage
{
  CIImage *image = [_inputImage imageByClampingToExtent];
  image = [image imageByApplyingGaussianBlurWithSigma:_inputRadius];
  image = [image imageByCroppingToRect:_inputImage.extent];
  return image;
}
```

I have verified that both `_inputImage` and `_inputRadius` exist when `outputImage` is called.

To be clear, `imageByClampingToExtent` is equivalent to using an explicit  `CIAffineClamp` filter.

---

Here's the method that creates my custom filter and applies it using `NSView#setBackgroundFilters`.

```
- (void)setBackgroundBlurRadius:(CGFloat)blurRadius
{
  _backgroundBlurRadius = blurRadius;

  if (_backgroundBlur == nil) {
    _backgroundBlur = [BlurFilter new];
    _backgroundBlur.name = @"blur";

    [self ensureLayerExists];
    self.backgroundFilters = @[_backgroundBlur];
  }

  [self.layer setValue:@(blurRadius)
            forKeyPath:@"backgroundFilters.blur.inputRadius"];
}
```

---

#### When I inspect the returned `image` (see the screenshot below), I see that the input image is a `GLTexture`. Could that be the issue?

I get the following error when I inspect the final `image`:

```
Cannot render image (with an input GL texture) using a metal-IG context.
```

Oddly, the blurred image renders regardless of the error, but the clamp is never applied before blurring.

[image]

Comment: Hi Alec, could you please post a screenshot of how the result looks like?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel How would a screenshot help you? The result looks the same whether or not I call the `imageByClampingToExtent` method, blurred but with "softened" edges (implying the clamp was not used).

Comment: Are the softened edges inside or outside the layer‘s bounds? What’s the extent of `inputImage` and the final `image` in you filter method?

Comment: Inside the layer's bounds. As shown in the diagram, the `inputImage` and the final `image` have the same extent.

Comment: Maybe the input image got a transparent border for some reasons, so that clamping effectively does nothing…